# Inserting a function inside href attribute which is being passed inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, call

I need to call a function in javascript inside an href attribute which itself is being passed in another javascript function.

```
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'document.write(getBaseURL());'/dao_comingsoon/assets/css/layoutArabic.css"/>');
```

But its not working.

Here is the getBaseURL function

```
function getBaseURL() {
var url = location.href;  // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));


if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
    // Base Url for localhost
    var url = location.href;  // window.location.href;
    var pathname = location.pathname;  // window.location.pathname;
    var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
    var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
    var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);

    return baseLocalUrl + "/";
}
else {
    // Root Url for domain name
    return baseURL + "/";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + getBaseURL() + '/dao_comingsoon/assets/css/layoutArabic.css"/>');
```

Comment: You should then check the output of `getBaseURL()` and see why it's not working.. Paste the function on your question so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Your getBaseURL() seems fine, please specify why it's not working, what error are you getting..